# enable rsync to run permanently

Tags: linux, rsync

I have two machines, both running on linux with centos 7.
I have installed the rsync packages on both of them and i am able to sync a directory from one machine to the other.

Right now i am doing the syncing manually, each time i want to sync i am running the next line:

```
rsync -r /home/stuff root@123.0.0.99/home
```

I was wondering if there is a way of configuring the rsync to do the syncing automatically, every some amount of time or preferably when there is a new file of sub directory in the home directory?

Thank you for your help.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to rsync every some amount of time you can use `cronjobs` which can be configured to run a specific command each amount of time and if you want to run rsync when there is an update or modification you can use `lsyncd`. check [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-mirror-local-and-remote-directories-on-a-vps-with-lsyncd) about use `lsyncd`

**Update:**
As links might get outdated, I will add this brief example (You are free to modify it with what works best for you):

First create an ssh key on the source machine and then add the public key at the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the destination machine.

In the source machine update this file `~/.ssh/config` with the following content:

```
# ~/.ssh/config
...
Host my.remote.server
    identityfile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    hostname 123.0.0.99
    user root
    port 22
...
```

And configure your lsyncd with the following then restart lsyncd's service

```
# lsyncd.conf
...
sync {
    default.rsyncssh,
    source="/home/stuff",
    host="my.remote.server",
    targetdir="/home/stuff",
    excludeFrom="/etc/lsyncd/lsyncd.exclude",
    rsync = {
         archive = true,
    }
}
...
```

Comment: thank you, i will check it. When using the `lsyncd`, is it still going to prompt me for the password every time it wants to sync?

Comment: No , you can configure ssh keys in order to login password-less, they have explained this too on that article

Comment: Does `lsyncd` only start a new `rsync` when the last `rsync` is done? I'm asking, because concurrent `rsync` make no sense to me.

Comment: @Ini, I am not sure but i think if its the same directory it might wait so it can send a new files list to be synced. I have not watched it while syncing a huge content :/

Answer (score 0):

You can setup an hourly cron job to do this.
rsync in itself is quite efficient in that it only transfers changes.
You can find more info about cron here: [cron](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html)